# SVG trouble with grouping

Tags: svg, drag-and-drop

I am new to SVG and am having difficulty grouping my multiple images into one.  It should look like a baseball diamond with bases. I have been able to draw everything and can click and drag each item, one at a time.  I am trying to move the entire image with one click. Any suggestions?

1. I have some JavaScript that allows my SVG to be moved around the page as separate pieces.

   1. SVG  I am trying to get this SVG element to stay together as one element when clicked and dragged around the page.  I am not sure how to do this.  I have tried using the  tag as well as several other container tags. As it is currently, everything is dragged seperately

   ```
       <rect class="draggable" x="62.226" y="62.227" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 210.7484   -87.2942)" fill="#088A08" stroke="#000000" width="297.043" height="297.041"
           transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" > </rect>
       <rect class="draggable" x="197.138" y="25.591" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 89.4451   -137.5392)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.219" height="27.219"
           transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></rect>
       <rect class="draggable" x="26.371" y="197.557" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 161.0362 33.5847)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.22" height="27.218"
           transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></rect>
       <rect class="draggable" x="369.362" y="197.298" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7072 -0.7072 0.7071 261.33 -209.0369)"   fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.22" height="27.217"></rect>
       <polygon class="draggable" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" points="194.912,364.45 227.945,364.45            227.378,383.915 211.578,399.717 195.778,383.915 "
           transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></polygon>
       </svg>

        </html>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to drag all shapes simultaneously , you need to group them.

**STEPS:-**

1) place all shapes in a 'g' tag

2) apply 'drag' on this g tag ('mousemove'). means apply translate matrix to this g.

3) on 'mouseup' event , update the latest values of individual shapes.

```
<g class='draggable'>
 <rect class="draggable" x="62.226" y="62.227" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 210.7484   -87.2942)" fill="#088A08" stroke="#000000" width="297.043" height="297.041"
        transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" > </rect>
    <rect class="draggable" x="197.138" y="25.591" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 89.4451   -137.5392)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.219" height="27.219"
        transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></rect>
    <rect class="draggable" x="26.371" y="197.557" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 161.0362 33.5847)" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.22" height="27.218"
        transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></rect>
    <rect class="draggable" x="369.362" y="197.298" transform="matrix(0.7071 0.7072 -0.7072 0.7071 261.33 -209.0369)"   fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" width="27.22" height="27.217"></rect>
    <polygon class="draggable" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" points="194.912,364.45 227.945,364.45            227.378,383.915 211.578,399.717 195.778,383.915 "
        transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" ></polygon>
</g>
```